# Rust unpacking the contents of an enum

Tags: rust

Rust noob here, I've been trying to unpack this enum from a grpc call (trying to access the `Vec<u8>` bytes) but so far I don't understand how I can access the underlying data.

Here is the proto:

```proto
message PublishRequest {
    string topic = 1;
    oneof optional_content {
        bytes content = 2;
    }
}

message KafkaResponse {
    bool success = 1;
    oneof optional_content {
        string content = 2;
    }
    
}

service KafkaStream {
    rpc Subscribe(stream PublishRequest) returns (stream KafkaResponse) {};
}
```

Rust code (I'm trying to reach `PublishRequest.optional_content.content`):

```rust
let output = async_stream::try_stream! {
            while let Some(publication) = stream.next().await {
                let message = publication?;
                let topic = message.topic.clone();
                if consumer_created_flag == false {
                    stream_topic = topic.clone();
                    consumer = Some(create_kafka_consumer(topic));
                    producer = Some(create_kafka_producer());
                    consumer_created_flag = true;
                }
                let content : Vec<u8> = match message.optional_content.clone() {
                    Some(message_content) => vec![], //trying to access content here instead
                    None =>vec![],
                };

                let reply = bridge::KafkaResponse {
                    content: format!("Hello {}!", "world"),
                };
                yield reply.clone();
            }
        };
```

`message.optional_content` is of type `std::option::Option<bridge::publish_request::OptionalContent>`

The underlying enum (from codegen):

```rust
pub mod publish_request {
    #[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Oneof)]
    pub enum OptionalContent {
        #[prost(bytes, tag = "2")]
        Content(::prost::alloc::vec::Vec<u8>),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the **whole type**:

```rust
let content : Vec<u8> = match message.optional_content.clone() {
    Some(OptionalContent::Content(message_content)) => message_content,
    None =>vec![],
};
```

You can check the examples in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-nested-structs-and-enums)